# How to perform operations on numbers with tolerances?

Tags: arithmetic

If I have `1±0.04 + 1±0.04` what would the tolerance of that equal?

What if we change it for a `-` or `*` or `/`?

I read somewhere that you should square the tolerances, add them together and then square root them. Which doesn't make sense because if I have the highest possible of each and add those together it wouldn't be within range of that answer.

Comment: What you "read somewhere" must be about adding normal-distributed random variables, whereas you're thinking about interval arithmetic. You need _first_ to be clear on what the notation $1\pm 0.04$ means to you in your context; _then_ you can ask which rules apply to that meaning.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you for your quick reply. I'm not sure quite sure I understand which rules will apply, so perhaps if I explain the application I'm using it for: I have a video at 25fps which means I can only jump forward one frame at a time which is 0.04 seconds so if I measure an event happening at x time I would need to say it's +-0.04 seconds right? Now I want to time how long the event goes for so I measure the end time as well y+-0.04 and subtract them. Which gives me y-x +- ???